# how to avoid running twice to fetch complete text with Selenium in headless mode

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the parts of the materials on the Zara website. Basically, what I did was:
step#1-open the website in headless mode
step#2-click the "see more" bottom and let the part I'm going to scrape "visible"
step#3-scrape the specific parts that I'm looking for

However, I found I need to run step#2 twice to get the complete text, which is not desirable... Can anyone tell me why this happens? Also, sometimes the code cannot return any text, so I need to wait for seconds and run step#2 again... this is also a problem.

My code is the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re
```

```
driver_path = 'D:/Python/Selenium/chromedriver'
option1 =  webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option1.add_argument("--headless")
option1.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

pro_url = 'https://www.zara.com/us/en/longline-down-jacket-limited-edition-p07522271.html?v1=132297981&v2=1988885'
# pro_url = 'https://www.zara.com/us/en/quilted-leather-crossbody-bag-p16774810.html'
# pro_url = 'https://www.zara.com/us/en/slit-straight-leg-pants-p07102160.html?v1=108948748&v2=1989249'
# pro_url = 'https://www.zara.com/us/en/soft-oversized-coat-p03046032.html?v1=157882610&v2=2024686'
# pro_url = 'https://www.zara.com/us/en/plain-sweatshirt-p05584602.html?v1=156787590&v2=1991272'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option1,executable_path=driver_path)
driver.get(pro_url)
```

```
try:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(@class,"expandable-text__view-more")]/span'))
except:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(@class,"product-detail-extra-detail-expandable__view-more")]/span'))
title_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[contains(@class,"structured-component-text zds-body-s")]')
part_ind = [(i-1) for i,s in enumerate(title_list) if re.compile("^[0-9]|^[1-9][0-9]|^(100)").search(s.text)]
part_text = [p.text for p in [title_list[i] for i in part_ind]]
cont_text = [i.text for i in title_list if re.compile("^[0-9]|^[1-9][0-9]|^(100)").search(i.text)]

print(part_text)
print(cont_text)

'''
result for running the first time
['OUTER SHELL', 'LINING']
['100% polyester', '100% polyester']
'''

'''
result for running the second time -- this is what I want:
['OUTER SHELL', 'LINING', 'FILLING']
['100% polyester', '100% polyester', '80% white duck down · 20% feather']
'''
```

I also paste the website screenshot for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your Selenium script isn't working but if you know the product id you can use the backend API to get this information with this endpoint:

[https://www.zara.com/us/en/product/{place_product_id_here}/extra-detail](https://www.zara.com/us/en/product/%7Bplace_product_id_here%7D/extra-detail)

```
import requests

product_id = 160264609

headers =   {
    'accept':'*/*',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
    }

url = f'https://www.zara.com/us/en/product/{product_id}/extra-detail?ajax=true'
data = requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()

for info in data[1]['components']:
    if info['datatype'] == 'paragraph':
        print(info['text']['value'])
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and got it! But one more question, if I hope to scrape all the products, how can I make sure all the web pages use the same user agent? Do I need to scrape the user agent for each page at first? Do the user agents default to be the same? Thank you so much!

Comment: You don't need to scrape the User-Agent, it's something that is set by the browser (scraper in our case), if you keep adding it to the requests like I did in my script then it will always be sent. The User-Agent will default to the same, it's not something you need to worry about for this script.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! But I ran into a new problem...is there a way to get the productid without manually typing it? I searched a lot online but cannot find a solution. I also tried to use `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="product-132297330"]/head/script[16]')` to find the embedded id but it doesn't work... I think unless I can automatically get all ids, I cannot use the API method:( Look forward to your reply!

Comment: Hi Vivian, I've just checked and it looks like you can get the id from the "v1=" part of the url, seems to work fine when checking that endpoint